# I want to merge values in an array if they have same id

Tags: javascript

I have an array Object which has same Id and different values. I need an output with same id and different values merged to the id.

Input:

```
let data = [{
    id: 1,
    value: 'Honda'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    value: 'Fiat'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    value: 'Porche'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    value: 'Benz'
  }
];
```

Output:

```
result = [{
      id: 1,
      value: ['Honda', 'Benz']
    }, {
      id: 2,
      value: ['Fiat', 'Porche']
    }
```

Comment: Great...you have an objective. So where is the code showing how you have tried to solve this and outline of the problems you are having doing it?

Answer (score 1):

Hope it will helps you. But this question is duplicate

```js
let data = [{
    id: 1,
    value: 'Honda'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    value: 'Fiat'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    value: 'Porche'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    value: 'Benz'
  }
];

var output = [];

data.forEach(function(item) {
  var existing = output.filter(function(v, i) {
    return v.id == item.id;
  });
  if (existing.length) {
    var existingIndex = output.indexOf(existing[0]);
    output[existingIndex].value = output[existingIndex].value.concat(item.value);
  } else {
    if (typeof item.value == 'string')
      item.value = [item.value];
    output.push(item);
  }
});

console.dir(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const data = [{
    id: 1,
    value: 'Honda'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    value: 'Fiat'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    value: 'Porche'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    value: 'Benz'
  }
];

const expectedResult = [{
      id: 1,
      value: ['Honda', 'Benz']
    }, {
      id: 2,
      value: ['Fiat', 'Porche']
    }
 ];
 
 const result = [];
 data.forEach((e, i) => {
    const indexOfExisting = result.findIndex(x => x.id === e.id);
    if (indexOfExisting === -1) {
      result.push({
          id: e.id,
          value: [e.value]
      })
    } else {
      result[indexOfExisting].value.push(e.value);
    }
 });
 
 // console.log(result)
 console.log(expectedResult)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to achieve it.

```js
let data = [{
    id: 1,
    value: 'Honda'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    value: 'Fiat'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    value: 'Porche'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    value: 'Benz'
  }
];


let result = data.reduce((acc, ele) => {

  let filtered = acc.filter(el => el.id == ele.id)
  if (filtered.length > 0) {

    filtered[0]["value"].push(ele.value);

  } else {
    element = {};
    element["id"] = ele.id;
    element["value"] = []
    element["value"].push(ele.value);
    acc.push(element)

  }

  return acc;
}, [])
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if it worked for you .Thanks @ShrutiMalkood